# Hybrid App running on Lock Screen

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing a Hybrid app that makes it possible to make phone calls using a telehpony server sold by the company I work for. the problem is that when there's an incomming call the phone rings but I have to be able to show the call on the lock screen, like a regular call.

Is this posible to acomplish using just JS? or maybe a library or framework?, the best case scenario would be getting it to work without using a cordova plugin.

EDIT:

Im using the Notification API to show notifications in the status bar, can I acomplish the result using the same API?

```
var options = {
                dir: 'auto',
                body: '',
                noscreen: false,
                sticky: true,
                timestamp: dts
            };
notification = new Notification('New Message from ' + mensaje.sourceagent, options);
```

Comment: Notification can be displayed over the lock screen on ANDROID.

Comment: Ok...right now will run on android, so...how can i acomplish that?, because im using Notification API and it just doesn't display there.. is there some option that i should be setting?, im updating the post with the Notification code that im using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As far as I know, it is not possible. That said, there are many simple plugins that would allow you to display notifications above the lock screen, such as [cordova-plugin-dialogs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-dialogs).

If a notification isn't enough and you need a full screen display, you will need a plugin to mix in native UI, such as [cordova-plugin-ace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ace). It's powerful, but a lot of work for a hybrid app.

Comment: Excelent!, that's what i wanted to know!, thank you for replying! i'll explore those options!